# SharedPreferences or SQlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-widget, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an Android AppWidget which displays a short text inputted from the configuration activity. I'm a bit confused when it's comes to storing the data, should I use sharedpreferences or SQlite Database?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It totally depend on your data, which you want to store.

**sharedpreferences**

- Small data
- Unstructured
- Like login info, user preffs, etc

**Sqlite**

- large data
- Structured
- Organized

Comment: Thanks, but if it's at least 2 strings maybe all the way up to say five. One with say maybe up to like 30-40 words and then the other just with small values like, text size value etc. should I use a database instead then?

Comment: for this just use `sharedPreferences` as you do not need any structure. and `sharedPreferences` will be best for you atm.

Comment: Okay Thanks, that's what I was hopping for (that's what I'm already using) :-) But I've just experienced loss of the shared preferences, and I'm pretty sure it didn't happen before, when I only saved a single string, and I therefore considered switching to SQlite, cause I've heard it's more reliable.

Comment: `sharedPreferences` is equal reliable as `Sqlite` :)

Comment: hm okay, I guess there's something wrong with my code then, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you want to store. 
With sharedPreferences you can store name - value data, with sqlite you have all the power of a relational database.

I'd say it depends on the amount of data and on the kind of query you need to perform on that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the data you're planning to store. If it's quite simple, sharedPreferences would do the job. If it's more complicated use DB.

Answer (score 0):

For a single string SharedPrefs will be much simpler.