# What is the easiest way to sharedpreference or sqlite android

Tags: android

I have an android application and when the user login , app shows a dialog (like a tutorial). I'd like to show this dialog just once / user. So if somebody login second time , doesn't show this dialog. What is the good solution? sqlite? or sharedpreference and how can i do it the fastest way.

Comment: for this type of task use sharepreference

Comment: you mean only to decide if show dialog or not? Well, sharedPrefs are easier to implement, for only one value to request, that´s the better way. If you have to do this for every user, then database is better.

Comment: Also, [SharedPrefs or SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631639/1380752)

Comment: If you need checking for each user independent use shared prefs, but instead of simple "key" string use "key".concat(userId). This does a trick.

Comment: You can use sharedpreferences for this purpose.You can set value of sharedpreferences value and then check that value whether user login first time or second.